# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when iterating over a hashmap with struts iterator

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

I am trying to use a hashmap to populate textfields in a jsp and bring back the modified values in the action class through the same hashmap i used to populate. In spite of many different approaches, i am failing to do so. I tried sending back an object list but i failed in that too(see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338286/editing-arraylist-of-objects-with-struts-2-form-tag/15343980?noredirect=1)). Its not necessary that i use the following approach, but **i just want to take a modified list back to action class through struts tags**. Please help me in this i already wasted a lot of time in this.

**Action class code**

```
private HashMap<String,Integer> coursesMarks;
//getters and setters

public String editCoursePage() {
        this.student = studentService.getStudent(rollNo);
        this.courseList = courseService.getStudentCourses(rollNo);
        coursesMarks = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for(Course c: courseList) {
            coursesMarks.put(c.getCourse(), c.getMarks());
        }
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

    public String editCourseAction() {

        System.out.print("inside of student action "
                + coursesMarks.size() + "\n\n\n");

        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }
```

**Inside the jsp**

```
<s:form action="editCourseAction" validate="true">
 Courses: 

<s:iterator value="coursesMarks" status="st">
<s:label ><s:property value="course" /></s:label>
<s:textfield name="coursesMarks[%{#st.index}].value" theme="simple"/>
<br />

</s:iterator>
<s:submit action="editCourseAction" value="submit" />
 </s:form>
```

Running this code throws this error...

```
    Mar 13, 2013 12:09:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:793)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:834)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:832)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.IteratorComponent.end(IteratorComponent.java:334)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.IteratorTag.doAfterBody(IteratorTag.java:87)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.editCourse_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fiterator_005f0(editCourse_jsp.java:251)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.editCourse_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fform_005f0(editCourse_jsp.java:174)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.editCourse_jsp._jspService(editCourse_jsp.java:104)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        .....and a long long list of error lines below this
```

If i use the following code

```
    <s:iterator value="coursesMarks" >
<s:label ><s:property value="course" /></s:label>
<s:textfield name="value" theme="simple"/>
```

It displays the values correctly but does not pass them back to the action class. Could you please tell me how to accomplish my task

Comment: do you have getters and setters for this text-field ,if you have then what is the name of textfield ,is it value?

Comment: getters and setters for which fields?? I have getters and ssetters for my hashmap and it is reading the values just fine. What i want to do is write the values back...

Comment: for textfields in your iterator, what is name of this element, do you have getters setters for text fields

Comment: I used name="coursesMarks[%{#st.index}].value" for the textfields because i want to write the modified values back to the action class. Would i need more setters and getters ?? Its a list, hence i cannot know the number of elements that are going to be written. \

Comment: you can not pass a list to a server, you can only pass parameters as a string,

Comment: So what would you suggest for my requirement ?? I want to pass a hashmap back to action class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JSP iterate over keys of your map and in `<s:textfield>` tag use key to get values. You JSP should look like that:

```
<s:form action="editCourseAction" validate="true">
 Courses: 

  <s:iterator value="coursesMarks.keys" var="coursekey">
    <s:label ><s:property value="course" /></s:label>
    <s:textfield name="coursesMarks['%{#coursekey}']" theme="simple"/>
    <br />

  </s:iterator>
  <s:submit action="editCourseAction" value="submit" />
</s:form>
```

Or iterate over map like you did and use `key` keyword to get values.

```
<s:iterator value="coursesMarks">
  <s:textfield name="coursesMarks['%{key}']" theme="simple"/>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Well this worked. Thank you very much aleksandr. You helped me twice in two days ;)